# C++ Size of std::vector Contiguous Section

Tags: c++, vector, struct, size

Within a struct, to minimize padding, one should declare the elements largest to smallest, correct?

An std::vector allocates memory on a section that is not necessarily contiguous, correct?

Within a struct, how many bits should I consider the std::vector to be when considering its placement within the struct with respect to padding?

Comment: ***An std::vector allocates memory on a section that is not necessarily contiguous, correct?*** Wrong.

Comment: ***Within a struct, to minimize padding, one should declare the elements largest to smallest, correct?*** Implementation defined.

Comment: @drescherjm: And naturally, the reverse normally works equally well.

Comment: @drescherjm: Sure, but the mechanism 99% of practical implementations use would follow this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're imagining something like this:

```
struct foo {
  // ...
  std::vector<T> vec;
  // ...
};
```

I think the thing you're missing is the distinction between the `std::vector` object itself and the memory it allocates for its elements. The `std::vector` itself takes up `sizeof(std::vector)` bytes, so will contribute at least this many bytes to a struct it is contained within if you account for padding.

Internally, the `std::vector` object allocates a contiguous region of memory elsewhere in which the elements are stored. To allow an increase or reduction in size, the `std::vector` may allocate different sizes of memory as you add or remove elements. However, this is irrelevent to your question, as this memory does not contribute to the size of the `std::vector` and not therefore to the size of the struct of which it is a member.

Comment: Thank you.  That was indeed what I was confused about.  Tequila does strange things to a man.  What's a good rule of thumb to determine sizeof(std::vector) before compiling knowing the object type it will store but not the amount of objects?

Comment: @Dr.McBucketO.ChickenM.D. That completely depends on how it's implemented, so you cannot say. The element type is unlikely to have any effect though.

Answer (score 4):

> Within a struct, to minimize padding, one should declare the elements largest to smallest, correct?

That depends. You may be optimizing for cache behavior in some cases which may not necessarily result in that ordering. On most implementations ordering things that way will result in a structure of the smallest size (with the least padding), but that's not guaranteed by the standard or anything like that.<sup>1</sup>

> An std::vector allocates memory on a section that is not necessarily contiguous, correct?

That is not correct. `vector` is required to use one contiguous section. See N3936 23.3.6.1/1:

> A `vector` is a sequence container that supports random access iterators. In addition, it supports (amortized) constant time insert and erase operations at the end; insert and erase in the middle take linear time. Storage management is handled automatically, though hints can be given to improve efficiency. The elements of a vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if `v` is a `vector<T, Allocator>` where `T` is some type other than `bool`, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`.

> Within a struct, how many bits should I consider the std::vector to be when considering its placement within the struct with respect to padding?

Vector can't see anything about the members in your structure; it only knows the size.

---

<sup>1</sup>Consider a hypothetical machine which has 4 byte `int`s and requires everything be 5 byte aligned. (I don't know of such a machine, but the standard is written in such a way that such a machine would be possible) In that case a structure like:

```
struct X
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
    char d;
};
```

would waste space because

```
struct X
{
    int a;
    char c;
    int b;
    char d;
};
```

would have each of the `char`s stored into the unused 5<sup>th</sup> byte. Which is why the standard leaves this implementation defined.